# PHP MySql update query not working,says:- Undefined Index

Tags: php, mysql

I have follow the tutorial of it where i want to update my database using two php files.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
    echo "<tr><form action =update.php method=post>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=Cname value='".$row['CustomerName']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=number name=size min=1 value='".$row['TableSize']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=date name=Adate value='".$row['DateA']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=time name=Atime value='".$row['TimeA']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=tel name=phonenumber value='".$row['PhoneNumber']."'></td>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=id value='".$row['TableID']."'>";
    echo "<td><input type=submit>";
    echo"</form></tr>";
}
?>
```

this is what i use for the first php file
as for the update.php:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

mysqli_select_db($con,'restaurant');

$sql = "UPDATE addtable SET CustomerName='$_POST[Cname]', TableSize='$_POST[size]', DateA='$_POST[Adate]',TimeA='$_POST[Atime]',PhoneNumber='$_POST[phonenumber]', WHERE TableID=$_POST[id]";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    header("refresh:1; url=AssignBooking.php");
else
    echo "Not Update";

?>
```

but the $sql line just doesn't work as it says that

> Undefined index: Cname and other indexes too.

Comment: huh? what's this got to do with phpmyadmin??

Comment: This is very old approach to displaying form to update!

Comment: your code is vulnarable to SQL Injection. check for `prepared statement` to prevent from `SQL Injection`

Comment: @e4c5 for that matter, what does it have to do with mysql?

Comment: good point @drew !

Comment: check the code of the link:- https://eval.in/655964 (only code not output),use it and check.Meanwhile your original form code is correct,leave as it is.

Answer (score 1):

put quotes outside the post variable:

```
$sql = "UPDATE addtable SET CustomerName='".$_POST['Cname']."', TableSize='".$_POST['size']."', DateA='".$_POST['Adate']."',TimeA='".$_POST['Atime']."',PhoneNumber='".$_POST['phonenumber']."', WHERE TableID=".$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: That wont work. your missing quotes.

Comment: @Xatenev long time going back to core php mysql query statements. now its ok..

Comment: no worries. good job

Answer (score 0):

According to your code put the name attributes value `'` single quote.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
    echo "<tr><form action =update.php method=post>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name='Cname' value='".$row['CustomerName']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=number name='size' min=1 value='".$row['TableSize']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=date name='Adate' value='".$row['DateA']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=time name='Atime' value='".$row['TimeA']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=tel name='phonenumber' value='".$row['PhoneNumber']."'></td>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name="id" value='".$row['TableID']."'>";
    echo "<td><input type=submit>";
    echo"</form></tr>";
}
?>
```

Put quotes accordingly

```
UPDATE addtable SET CustomerName='".$_POST['Cname']."',TableSize='".$_POST['size']."',    DateA='".$_POST['Adate']."',TimeA='".$_POST['Atime']."',PhoneNumber='".$_POST['phonenumber']."' WHERE TableID=$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: i tried before the attributes value with " but it will have an error saying that it expected a semicolon

Comment: Do not use like this `value='".$row['CustomerName']."'` instead of that `value=".$row['CustomerName']."`

Comment: i mean when i put "Cname", it will expect a semicolon after the " which wouldn't make the code works

Comment: Ok, change it to `'` like this: `name='Cname'`

Comment: What is the error again?

Comment: I have tried your way and it still doesn't work but i have set the name='Cname' and as for the update.php i couldn't put "" in between Cname as it will become an undefined constant.

Comment: Replace with this: `UPDATE addtable SET CustomerName=$_POST['Cname'], TableSize=$_POST['size'], DateA=$_POST['Adate'],TimeA=$_POST['Atime'],PhoneNumber=$_POST['phonenumber'], WHERE TableID=$_POST['id']`

Comment: its the same whether if i put " or ' in between Cname and the others

Comment: @DarrenE  check the code of the link:- https://eval.in/655964 (only code not output),use it and check.Meanwhile your original form code is correct,leave as it is